# Convention for empty intersection with respect to set A

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Assume we are given two sets of points $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, and two disks $D_1, D_2$.

Is there a convention if we want to express that the intersection of $D_1$ and $D_2$ is empty i.e $D_1 \cap D_2 = \emptyset$, but *only* with respect to the points in $A$?
Something like $D_1 \cap_{A} D_2 = \emptyset$ seems a bit crude.

Comment: What about $A\cap D_1 \cap D_2=\emptyset$?

Comment: Ah of course. That sounds more than reasonable to me. Thanks @GhostAmarth.